# Sorting integer in jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, integer, rowsorter

when i click the 'Price' radiobutton it sorts the Price Row but in this order

- 1
- 11
- 12
- 13
- 2
- 21
- 200
- 3
- 32
- 300

how can i fix it? im still new in java. please help me. thanks. :D

```
rdbtnNewRadioButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            DefaultRowSorter sorter = ((DefaultRowSorter)table.getRowSorter());
            List <RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<RowSorter.SortKey>();
            sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(4, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
            sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys); 

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- override `getColumnClass` in your `XxxTableModel`, default class is `String`, the your result from `RowSorter` is correct
- use `Integer.Class`

Answer (score 1):

Write your own comparator and then

```
sorter.setComparator(int column, Comparator<?> comparator)
```

refer this [Why does my JTable sort an integer column incorrectly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592192/why-does-my-jtable-sort-an-integer-column-incorrectly)

Comment: how to write my own comparator

Comment: Take a look at the Class IntComparator in the link provided http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592192/why-does-my-jtable-sort-an-integer-column-incorrectly

Comment: i don't quite get it. @.@ sorry still new

Comment: not neccessary to use custom Comparator, basic stuff about getColumnClass

Answer (score 0):

Convert your data column to an integer type in order to have the correct order.

```
SELECT
    ...,
    CAST(YourColumnName as INT) as YourColumnName
    ...
FROM...
```

Comment: @Rohan21: should you rebinddata after setting sort key?!