# Sorting ascending and descending in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

```
public projectframe() {
    initComponents();
    jTable2.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
}
```

I want to sort my data I used that code for sorting but sometimes in the Integer error.

like that I can't sort with true
[image: screenshot]

Comment: It looks like `getValueAt` returns `String` instead of `Integer`

Comment: can you show more code?

Comment: Can you check whether value set in the table for Quantity and Price  is Integer?

Comment: DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
        name.setText(jTable2.getValueAt(jTable2.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
        quantity.setText(jTable2.getValueAt(jTable2.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString());
        price.setText(jTable2.getValueAt(jTable2.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString());

Comment: Java is performing a "natural" sort on the strings, which is based on the textual or ascii based values, not the numerical values.  You need to store physical `int` values in the columns so they are sorted using their numerical values instead

Comment: [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592192/why-does-my-jtable-sort-an-integer-column-incorrectly) and [for an explanation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/why-do-some-sorting-methods-sort-by-1-10-2-3)