# Sorting Double/int values in Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, columnsorting

I've been trying to sort double values in a JTable, but it hasn't worked, even after overriding the getColumnClass.
Here is part of the code:

```
DefaultTableModel model = generateModel(((Programmer) user).getApps());
        tab = new JTable(model) {
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return column == 4;
            }
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                switch (column) {
                    case 0:
                        return Integer.class;
                    case 3:
                        return Double.class;
                    default:
                        return String.class;
                }
            }
};
tab.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        

//....

public DefaultTableModel gerarModeloTabela(ArrayList<Applications> apps){

        Object[][] data = new Object[apps.size()][5];
        for (int i = 0; i < apps.size(); i++) {
            data[i][0] = apps.get(i).getId();
            data[i][1] = apps.get(i).getName();
            data[i][2] = apps.get(i).getDescription();
            data[i][3] = apps.get(i).getValue();

            int line = i;

            JButton b = new JButton("+");
            data[i][4] = b;
           

              
        Object columns[] = {"ID", "Name", "Description", "Value", ""};


        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);

        return model;
    }
```

Could someone help me fixing this.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6592538/418556) shows how to correctly sort `Integer` values. It should be obvious how to adapt it for `Double` values. For better help sooner, post an [mre] as seen in that answer. It's also helpful to add relevant tags (I did). Likely some kind person will be along shortly to find an appropriate duplicate with which to close this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It was very helpful, although I had to implement the comparator to achieve what i need